# How to get local sync folder of one drive sync?

Tags: onedrive

I have installed OneDrive on my local machine. Is there any way to get root folder/sync path of one drive ? I am looking for a programmatic way to fetch the root folder of one drive. Is there any API or interfaces through which I can access these details ? I want this API or interface for MacOS platform.

Answer (score 0):

the information is in the registry.

Find the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts`, you'll see your accounts as sub-keys. In them, look for the string value named `UserFolder`.

Comment: There is no registry on MacOS.